# Getting 2 divs to align

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding. Was hoping someone could help me get the 2 div's inside the 'connector' class to join up and be aligned together in the center. On the webpage, the placeholder and button divs are far apart from each other. I know I have to work the CSS, but I'm unsure where to start. Been working on this for awhile. Thank you

```
<div class="connector">
    <div class="results">
         <div id=photoResult class="result">
             <p>Placeholder</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "buttons">
        <button id="button">Get Photo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"On the webpage, the placeholder and button divs are far apart from each other"* - can you provide the CSS? Also, what do you mean by *"join up"* and *"aligned together in center"*?

Comment: Can you add your css so we can see where the problem is ?

Comment: Please see [ask]. The internet's chock full of layout guides. You need to pick a direction and make an effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox.

```
.connector {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display them inline-block:

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#left, #right {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
         <div id=photoResult class="result">
             Placeholder
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "right">
        <button id="button">Get Photo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```